# map based on specific type of stream

Tags: ffmpeg

Consider the following file

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'infile.mp4':
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1038
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 386 kb/s
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s
```

I would like to run a command that uses the video and only the stereo audio.
With this particular file I could just run

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c copy -map v -map :2 outfile.mp4
```

However this will not work if the audio streams are switched. How can I tell
FFmpeg to use the 2 channel audio only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
ffprobe -v 0 -of csv -show_streams infile.mp4 | awk '/stereo/, $0 = ":" $2' FS=,
```

Result

```
:2
```